# Can I start docker service in azure cli?

Tags: azure, docker, command-line-interface

I'm trying to start the docker service in azure cli and it doesn't work!

The docker command exists, but the daemon cannot be started. I tried with:

1. service docker start
2. systemctl start docker.service

None of them worked.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Azure Cloud Shell is a cli experinece, not a host to run your workloads on